# Problem for uploading a csv file with readr::read_csv

Tags: r, readr

I want to download a csv file on R with `readr::read_csv`.
These are the 9 columns for the header :

```
DATAFLOW,LAST UPDATE,freq,unit,coicop,geo,TIME_PERIOD,OBS_VALUE,OBS_FLAG
```

And these are the corresponding values for each column :

```
ESTAT:PRC_HICP_MIDX(1.0),19/04/23 11:00:00,M:Mensuel,"I15:Indice, 2015=100",CP01:Produits alimentaires et boissons non alcoolisÃ©es,"EA:Zone euro (EA11-1999, EA12-2001, EA13-2007, EA15-2008, EA16-2009, EA17-2011, EA18-2014, EA19-2015, EA20-2023)",1996-01,70.73,
```

Last week i had trouble downloading the data with the `read.csv` method because of the different commas in the columns (e.g : `"I15:Indice, 2015=100"` which is a data for one column).
I tried with the `readr::read_csv` method and it solved my problem and downloaded perfectly the data in 9 columns, but today I tried to run my code again and it wasn't working do you know what could be the problem knowing I didn't change anything in the code neither in the database. And if you don't know why do you know what other method I could use to download the data correctly ?

Comment: Can you provide your data using `dput()` or `head(dput())` to give us a better sense of what your data looks like?

Comment: structure(list(DATAFLOW = c("ESTAT:PRC_HICP_MIDX(1.0),19/04/23 11:00:00,M:Mensuel,\"\"I15:Indice, 2015=100\"\",CP01:Produits alimentaires et boissons non alcoolisées,\"\"EA:Zone euro (EA11-1999, EA12-2001, EA13-2007, EA15-2008, EA16-2009, EA17-2011, EA18-2014, EA19-2015, EA20-2023)\"\",1996-01,70.73,\"\r",
Here is the first line of my output with head(dput(df))

Comment: Can you add the entire line to your original question and make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?